# React redux state is not loading on production build

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, production

So i m having a very wired issue with react app its working fine in localhost but not working on production server.
**In detail**
**im using react with redux and redux state is coming empty on production server**

Image 1: Localhost Screen shot (which is working fine)

[image: Image 1]
Image 2: Production Server Image Where menu state is empty (Not Working)
[image: Image 2]

**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React  from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
//global settings
import {SETTINGS} from '../../global/settings';

//calling component
import MenuItem from './menu-items.component';

//menu acctions
import {SET_MENU,SET_LOADING_STATUS} from '../../redux/menu/menu.actions';

//global JSON 
import {JSON_URLS} from '../../global/json-urls';

//Nav bar 
import {Collapse, Navbar,NavbarToggler,NavbarBrand,Nav,NavbarText,NavItem,} from 'reactstrap';

//reactstrap Spinner for loading
import { Spinner } from 'reactstrap';

class Menu extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
           isOpen: false,
           setIsOpen: false, 
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        const {SET_MENU} = this.props;
        const {SET_LOADING_STATUS}= this.props;

        fetch('https://wp2.neton.com.au/wp-json/wp-api-menus/v2/menus/2')
        .then(response =>response.json())
        .then(menu=>SET_MENU(menu))
        .then(menu=>SET_LOADING_STATUS(false))
    }

    render(){
        const {menu}=this.props;
        const {loading}=this.props;
        const {isOpen, setIsOpen}= this.state;
        console.log('Menu '+menu);
        
        //for Menu
        const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

        return(
            
            <div className="menu-menu">      
                { 
                (Array.isArray(menu.items))
                ?    
                    <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
                        <NavbarBrand href="/">{SETTINGS.SITE_NAME}</NavbarBrand>
                        <NavbarToggler onClick={toggle} />
                        <Collapse isOpen={isOpen} navbar>
                            <Nav className="mr-auto" navbar>
                                {(menu.items).map(menu=><MenuItem key={menu.id} menu={menu} />)}
                                <NavItem><Link to={`${SETTINGS.BASE_URL}posts`} className="nav-link">All Posts</Link></NavItem>
                                <NavItem><Link to={`${SETTINGS.BASE_URL}pages`} className="nav-link">All Pages</Link></NavItem>
                            </Nav>
                            <NavbarText>Simple Text</NavbarText>
                        </Collapse>
                    </Navbar>     
                :
                    (loading) 
                        ? 
                        <Spinner color="dark" className="text-center d-block m-auto" />
                        : 
                        ''
                }
            </div>
        )

    }

}

const mapStateToProps=(state)=>({
    menu:state.menu.menu,
    loading:state.menu.loading
})
const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>({
    SET_MENU:menu=>dispatch(SET_MENU(menu)),
    SET_LOADING_STATUS:status=>dispatch(SET_LOADING_STATUS(status))

})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Menu);
```

**

Comment: I think SET_MENU is supposed to set the menu but the images don't show that action. Could it be your fetch failed?

Answer (score 0):

OK FINALLY FOUND THE BUG!!

so it has nothing to do with **redux** but the issue is related to **react-router-dom**

so when we will build production we have to make sure two things

1. package.json should include
   "homepage": "https://YOUR-DOMIAN/DIRECTORY",
   DIRECTORY:where the build files will go
2. in ROUTER THIS DIRECTORY SHOULD ALSO BE MENTION

```html
 <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/DIRECTORY/" component={HomePage} />
 <Switch>
```

I was having issue with 2 point hope it helps others :)